# Speakers hum only when nothing is playing

Tags: audio, speakers, ground

Disclaimer: I know it's a ground-loop issue, of course, and there are multiple ways how to fix this, but the interesting bit that I wanted to point out here is that usually gound-loop hum is present constantly, but in this particular case humming stops as soon as anything (system sound, Youtube, Spotify or any other sound) is played through the output, and resumes a few seconds after sound has stopped.

I'm just curious what's the reason behind this - is it something to do with the computer motherboard disabling a DAC after a short period of inactivity, ot it's the built-in amplifier in the active speakers that does someting strange during periods where no input is present?

Comment: If you play a sound source then stop it abruptly, does the hum 'switch in' after a few seconds, or does it 'slope in' like someone turned a volume knob up?

Comment: @Tetsujin  Hum disappares a second before youtube or other sound starts playing, and appears instantly around 3 seconds after audio is paused. There is no fade-in or fade-out - this is what puzzles me. Also this happens both in Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19 that is running on this machine.

Comment: All I can tell from that info is it's "software" somewhere, but I have no idea where. You're going to have to test each component separately.

Comment: Just curious, is the behavior same if you connect your headphones to the Line-Out? Do you hear the hum when nothing is played? This may clarify if it's coming from the Sound card or generated in the external speaker circuit.

Comment: In my case, it is independent of the connection of the speakers to the PC, i.e. I disconnect  them from the sound card. The buzz effect is exactly the same: Loud when I power the speakers on, then it fades to a much lower leven and remains constant and little auditable. Also, it is independent of the level the volume button is set. That is, if there's no audio at all, the buzz is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your power cable connected to your PC is faulty or if the outlet it is plugged into is faulty. Also check if any nearby devices have some sort of faulty power connection, as they can cause static interference. If none of these work then it is probably an internal issue with the power supply or motherboard.

I had this issue twice before. Once was because I am using a mixer with two different computers, therefore the power being transmitted is different which causes a ground-loop. I fixed it with an audio ground I found on Amazon, this is probably the best one you can find for cheap: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01N10AQ76/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N10AQ76)

I have used other cheap audio grounds and can definitely say that this one works much better as it does not nullify the bass on your sounds.

The second time I had this problem was because a laptop I had plugged in nearby had a faulty charger which was causing interference with all nearby audio devices, even if they were not connected to the laptop. I fixed this by replacing the faulty charger.

Comment: In my case, the buzz is independent of the connection of the speakers to the computer.